# Permutations of $abcde$ which the first character is $a$, $b$ or $c$ and last character is $c$, $d$ or $e$

Tags: combinatorics

How many permutations of $abcde$ are there in which the ﬁrst character is $a$, $b$ or $c$ and last character is $c$, $d$ or $e$.

Don't know how to start this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sketch**

Split into cases. $c$ is the only character shared between the option sets for the first and last position, so we can handle that separately. If $c$ is either at the start or at the end we get the following cases:

1. Starts with $c$ and ends with one of $d,e$.
2. Ends with $c$ and starts with one of $a,b$.

What's left is the case where $c$ is neither at the start nor at the end. I'll leave you to finish this off.